# Temporary JavaScript onclick toggle

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick, toggle

I am having a terrible time figuring this one out. I have a form.

```
<form id="form1" .. target="right" action="blablah">
<input .. />
<input type="submit" id="ycsubmit" onclick="..." value="Go!" />
</FORM>
```

I have a function I need executed on submit: ycClick();

Once ycClick() is executed I need to toggle onClick to null for 30 seconds, then toggle back so that if pressed again after 30s it will execute ycClick() a second time,then disable it for another 30s,  and so forth. I've tried this 100 different ways but this is what I've got now:

```
function ycClick(){
...
}

var isEnabled = true;

function toggleSubmit() {
    if (isEnabled = true) {
        document.getElementById("ycsubmit").onclick = null;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ycsubmit").onclick = timer();
    } 
//isEnabled = !isEnabled;
}

function timer(){
ycClick();
toggleSubmit();
setTimeout("toggleSubmit()", 30000);
}
```

Then I've got onclick set to trigger timer();
As is, this sets off timer(), which sets off ycClick() and then toggles onclick to null, but does not toggle it back after 30 seconds. I suspect it has something to do with this line:

```
isEnabled = !isEnabled;
```

but removing made no difference, it still operates exactly the same.

Comment: Recreating your problem here http://jsfiddle.net/ and pasting the link here may get you more help.

Comment: @AlexWayne is right, but I'll try to give you some general guidance below.

Comment: Your problem is probably from this common error `isEnabled = true`. `=` assign a value while `==` is the compare operator you want to use. Also to assign a function you shouldn't put `()` otherwise what you are assigning is the result of the function call, not the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function ycClick () {
    var timestamp = +( new Date );
    if ( ycClick.timestamp && timestamp - ycClick.timestamp < 30000 ) return;
    ycClick.timestamp = timestamp;

    // the actual code of the function
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/znKRC/7/

In my demo, click on the button repeatedly, and you'll notice that the second part of the function is only executed every 3 seconds. So, the first three lines of the function above make sure that the subsequent code is only executed if it has not been executed in the last 30 seconds.

Comment: F*cking beautiful!! this was my original idea but I was convinced settimeout would be easier.. now to see if I can apply it to my situation! thank you!

Comment: What the heck! it still doesn't work.. http://jsfiddle.net/ggordie/znKRC/11/ I literally copy/pasted your exact code!! I have a new date specified previously on this page as well but tht doesn't  explain why it isn't working in the overly simplified version I just linked to.. please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Gordie (1) you have a syntax error - a superfluous `}` brace in line 4, (2) you wrote `onclick="timer();"`, but the function name is `ycClick`. I've corrected those two things: http://jsfiddle.net/znKRC/12/ (I've also changed the button from "submit" to "button" for the purposes of the demo.)

Comment: aww man, thanks for stickin with me sime. next time youre in florida you gotta let me buy you a brew. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to improve your code; some of them are simple errors, others indicate that you should learn about some other features of the DOM and JavaScript runtime. Here's what I noticed, in order:

#### Errors

- You made a common mistake when testing `if (isEnabled = true){`. A single `=` is an assignment, so your code is not testing whether isEnabled is true. Instead it's testing the result of the assignment, which is always `true`. Use a triple equals `===` to test whether `isEnabled` is currently true. *(You'll also see a double equals `==`, but this operator can have unexpected effects and is less strict, so avoid it mostly.)*
- On the line `document.getElementById("ycsubmit").onclick = timer();`, you should leave off the parentheses after `timer`. With the parentheses, you are **executing the `timer` function**, instead of assigning a reference to that function. The onclick method is being set to the return value of `timer`, which, since you didn't specify a `return` statement, will be `undefined`.
- You are never setting `isEnabled` to false! In your current setup, you should have left the `isEnabled = !isEnabled` line in!

#### Approach problems

- The answer above mine demonstrates a better approach to disabling form submit. You shouldn't try to set and unset an onclick handler; instead, you should handle repeated clicks inside the handler itself. In fact, it can be even simpler: if this form is submitting normally rather than being validated by JavaScript or sent through AJAX, then you can simply disable the input and not worry about reenabling it, since the form will refresh or navigate away when the server completes processing the form submit. The page will either disappear or reload with an enabled submit button!
- You shouldn't use the click event on a submit button to block form submission. Forms have a submit event for this purpose. It's possible to submit forms via the return key in some browsers, and that will bypass your click event. You should subscribe to the form's submit event.
- You shouldn't be using the "onclick" attribute to assign event handlers in the first place. You should be adding event listeners to your DOM elements. This results in more flexible events--you can assign multiple events to the same element, for instance--and better handling of the scope in which events execute. Finally, it separates the presentation and behavior of the document from its content. This is the practice with jQuery and other popular libraries. I realize that this requires more coding, but that's why manipulation libraries like jQuery exist. You should give it a shot!

Comment: here is a better explanation of what I'm doing. the page is never refreshed. ycClick is a counter and the form is only used to display it, and add +1 everytime the form is submitted. it has another purpose as well, and it does have to be on the submit button, can't just be a regular button. please look at my implementation of Šime Vidas' example here and tell my what I am continuing to do wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/ggordie/znKRC/11/ in the mean time I am going to try my method again using some of your pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is use the JavaScript "setTimeout(function(){},t)" where function is the command to execute and t = time in Milli-Seconds.

also you may want to set the object style in order to hide the element.